# Using cmd.exe to record error message

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-prompt

I need to copy paste a very long error message I get in the command console but the top of it always gets cut off.

I tried increasing buffer to 999 but that didn't do anything.

The command I am running that gives me the error is `vagrant up` so I also tried `vagrant up > output.txt` but this just creates an empty file.

How can I save the entire error output that is sent to cmd console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `vagrant up > output.txt` you are actually redirecting `STDOUT` to the file and not `STDERR`. To redirect `STDERR` choose handle `2` like below

```
vagrant up 2>output.txt
```

In case, you want both standard output and standard error to redirect to same file then do like below

```
vagrant up > output.txt 2>&1
```